# Detecting location of substring within string in R

Tags: r, string, stringr

Consider the following string:

```
"NIKE STORE COVENT GARDEN"
```

Suppose we are attempting to detect which is the brand that matches from the following vector:

```
brands <- c("ADIDAS", "NIKE", "PUMA", "COVENT", "CONVERSE")
```

Below is what I did with the resulting output:

```
library(stringr)
> brands[str_detect("NIKE STORE COVENT GARDEN", brands)]
[1] "COVENT"    "NIKE"
```

Clearly the brand here is "NIKE", and I know that it is consistently located before the location. Is there some way I can define a rule that in the case I detect multiple brands, that I select the one that appears earlier in the string?

NOTE: In the example above we conveniently have the brand name appear in the beginning of the string. However we sometimes have the case that the string we are considering is of the form "0123 NIKE STORE COVENT GARDEN"

Comment: which version of R and stringr are you using ?

Comment: R version 3.2.1; stringr version 1.0.0

Comment: appart being with r 3.2.2, I got the correct integer output (not text),  I suspect something in your R environment messing with it. You code as is return `[1] 2 4`

Comment: @Tensibai you're right, sorry. I edited my question. Please consult the new version

Comment: As above, being used as selector or just the integer does not change anything. I still have a correct result (NIKE first) So I suspect `brands` is not in the order you think it is (maybe sorted before ? this would give this output)

Comment: Yeah I cannot count that the order will always be so, since brands in my actual case is alphbetically ordered, and the strings beings considered are not, nor can they be ordered

Comment: To adjust a little more: the Brand will always be the first word of the sentence ? (seems we need a more complete example set of input and expected output)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can consider using str_locate instead of str_detect. What about :

```
brands[which.min(str_locate("NIKE STORE COVENT GARDEN", brands)[,1])]
```

Comment: Or in base, `which(sapply(brands,grepl,x="NIKE STORE COVENT GARDEN"))[1]`